# How can I verify a cryptographic hash created by Python's Passlib using Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, security, hash, pbkdf2

I have a backend application written in Python used by the content managers of my site. Users' passwords are hashed using [passlib's pbkdf2_sha512](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha512) function. I began to develop the frontend application for which I decided to use nodejs with React for UX reasons.

Now my problem is I can't figure out how can I verify the passwords hashed by passlib using nodejs for authenticating my users. Passlib's implementation seems too specific to me and I'm not really into crypto stuff to figure it out.

I have the MCF so I know the algorithm and digest type, the salt, the number of iterations and the key length. How can I verify this output from passlib in node? Should I rather choose another algorithm better supported by both platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I turned to sha512_crypt instead and found a nice library for node called [sha512crypt-node](https://github.com/mvo5/sha512crypt-node). The README itself contains an example for both Python and Node, exactly what I needed. Here's a little example for ppl. using these platforms:

Python:

```
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt

orig = "password"
h = sha512_crypt.encrypt(orig)
print("hash", h)
# h for eg. is $6$rounds=100000$5YnTXatKh4b1pLjp$3QQjVIfjrbiTakj.wkaw1woAcFiPRAjJP2U/b3BiGW4m8OvI8x0tgw1bb63dNQWMUl1uYNDBcTO3tWgrJ6eHh1

okay = sha512_crypt.verify(orig, h)
print("verified", okay)
```

Node:

```
var sha512crypt = require("sha512crypt-node").sha512crypt;

// origHash is the hash generated by passlib    
var origHash = "$6$rounds=100000$5YnTXatKh4b1pLjp$3QQjVIfjrbiTakj.wkaw1woAcFiPRAjJP2U/b3BiGW4m8OvI8x0tgw1bb63dNQWMUl1uYNDBcTO3tWgrJ6eHh1",
    parts = origHash.split('$'),
    rounds = parts[2],
    salt = '$' + parts[1] + '$' + rounds + '$' + parts[3],
    password = "password";

var hash = sha512crypt(password, salt);
console.log("verified", hash === origHash);
```

Answer (score 2):

We had exactly the same Problem but switching to sha512crypt was not an option. In our case the passwords were generated with flask-security. The examples below cover regular passlib and flask-security hashes, which first generate a HMAC with a secret salt and use it as the pbkdf2-sha512 password. See code below.

Source is on GitHub: https://github.com/badzong/node-verify-flask-security-passwords

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var pbkdf2_sha512 = require('pbkdf2-sha512');

function b64trimmed(buf) {
        return buf.toString('base64').replace(/=*$/, '').replace('+', '.');
}

function b64decode(str) {
        // . in Base64?
        str = str.replace('.', '+');
        if (str.length % 4) {
                str += '='.repeat(4 - str.length % 4);
        }
        return new Buffer(str, 'base64');
}

function get_hmac(secret, password) {
        var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret).update(password).digest('base64');

        return hmac;
}

function get_hash(password, salt, rounds) {

        // FIXME: KeyLenBytes is hardcoded
        var h = b64trimmed(pbkdf2_sha512(password, salt, rounds, 64));
        var joined_hash = ['', 'pbkdf2-sha512', rounds, b64trimmed(salt), h].join('$');

        return joined_hash;
}

function verify_hash(password, stored_hash) {
        var scheme = stored_hash.split('$')[1];
        var rounds = stored_hash.split('$')[2];
        var salt = stored_hash.split('$')[3];

        // FIXME: Maybe throw an exception
        if (scheme !== 'pbkdf2-sha512') {
                return false;
        }

        var h = get_hash(password, b64decode(salt), rounds);

        return h === stored_hash;
}

function new_hash(password, rounds) {

        // FIXME: Salt size is hardcoded
        var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);

        return get_hash(password, salt, rounds);
}

var password = 'Example Password';

// Usage:
var h = new_hash(password, 20000);
console.log('HASH ' + h);
console.log('VERIFY ' + verify_hash(password, h));

// Usage for passwords generated with flask_security:

// SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT is set in config.py and used by flask-security
var SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = 'Many random bytes...';

var password_hmac = get_hmac(SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT, password);
var h = new_hash(password_hmac, 20000);
console.log('HASH ' + h);
console.log('VERIFY ' + verify_hash(password_hmac, h));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly none of the mentioned solutions work for me (passlib 1.7.4). I ended up writing my own little node-module. If someone is still stuck on this feel free to use [node-passlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-passlib)

Example:

```
import nodePasslib from 'node-passlib';

// python-passlib PBKDF2-SHA512 hash
const pbkdf2Hash = '$pbkdf2-sha512$25000$JKSU8r63VgrBmHMO4RwjRA$bUL/owmBl8slaj.fjONmdRijzOs4Lo6EwbKtoA6EPX1hs1BCdg3JRjfkR3WX5/mZ4cIhtJhFVFxrLlq1lHfpQw';

nodePasslib.verify('yourpassword', pbkdf2Hash);
// true

nodePasslib.verify('wrongpassword', pbkdf2Hash);
// false
```

The default keylen is set to 64. If you use a SHA256 encoded hash you need to specify a different keylen:

```
nodePasslib.verify('yourpassword', pbkdf2Hash, 32);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Consider adding here a small example on how to use this module.